# How to make site with only PDF-file and nothing more

Tags: pdf, web, static-files

I didn't find any information about this.

I want to upload website as a PDF-file, if you don't understand, I'll explain.

If you type something in Google, and after that type `filetype:pdf`, you'll see websites, but it will be only PDF-file, nothing more. The same can be with other types of files, such as `ppt`, `xls` and `doc`.

How can I make a website containing only a PDF file, a presentation file, an Excel file, or a document?

Comment: Your question is too vauge for a super specific answer, but generally (assuming you're hosting it yourself), you would set your web server to host it as a static file and depending on what it is (and how you set it up) it could display in the browser or automatically download. If you're using a web hosting provider, then they likely have an easy way to do this

Comment: @cocomac , I will try to do it :)

Comment: What web server are you using?  Do you want the file to download, or be viewed in the browser?

Comment: This needs more focus.  If  you just want to make unprotected static files of any types available, one way that can scale up to essentially infinite users is to use an Amazon Web Services S3 bucket.  No web server is needed at all.  If you need more than that please edit your question to add a more detailed explanation of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

In general a "web site" must be Hyper Text Markup (HTM) usually starting `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` thats the media the "web" is built on. Prior to that users linked to a File Transfer Server (BBS) to get their pages of data that were downloaded as text streams (Downloads).

Very little has changed in that most basic ask for a telegram and get a txt msg.

Modern browsers are still very much like the word processing GUIs that first ran on consoles but nowadays serve streams of flashy image based ads. So Luddite I  am I think we went backwards trading GIE commercialism for GUI speed.

Anyway to the nub of your question those robotic scrapped links are direct to a pages embedded / linked binary File Transfer (actually in comms terms converted as text for hyper space download, and reassembly in your editing browser) so are not standalone web sites.